# node.js page render not working - even when server don't throw any errors

Tags: node.js

**index.js file:**

```
 var express = require('express');

 var dummy = require('./routes/dummy.js');
 var showdata = require('./routes/showdata.js');

 var app = express();
 app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

 app.use('/dummy', dummy);
 app.use('/showdata', showdata);
```

**dummy.js file:**

```
  var express = require('express');
  var router = express.Router();

  router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('dummy');
    next();
  });

  module.exports = function() {
    var precious_data = 'precious_data - from dummy.js file';
    console.log(precious_data);
    return router;
  };
```

**showdata.js file:**

```
 var express = require('express'); var router = express.Router();


 var dummyReq = require('./dummy.js');
 var showModuleExports = dummyReq();


 router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
   res.render('showdata', { renderData : showModuleExports });
 });

 module.exports = router;
```

---

Server don't show any error but I can't display my page... In browser when I type localhost it's loading over and over. Any idea what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
app.use('/dummy', dummy);
```

should instead be:

```
app.use('/dummy', dummy());
```

because that module is exporting a function that *returns* the router.

Also, calling `next()` after something like `res.render()` is not necessary and may cause unintended behavior in case you have another route handler that may match the request.

Comment: EDIT: BTW why - var consoleData = dummyReq.precious_data (var consoleData = showModuleExports.precious_data) isn't working?

Comment: Why would it? `precious_data` is just a local variable, it's not a property on the object you're exporting...

Comment: Hmmm got it. But when I added precious: 'just for test'; to module.exports = function() {var precious_data = 'var precious_data - from form.js file';precious: 'lol';return router;} and when trying to display it's text by with console.log(dummyReq.precious); it's not working either.

Comment: Literally adding `precious: 'lol';` on a line is not exporting anything. What that actually does is create a label followed by a string literal, which is essentially a no-op. You might want to read up on [how modules work](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html) in node and/or the [MDN JavaScript Guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide) if you're a bit rusty on JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks. I thought that I'm exporting everything inside module.exports... so I'm surprised that I can't get to variables I did set inside...

Comment: No, javascript doesn't work like that. You have to either assign what you want to export to `module.exports` *or* attach whatever values to the default `exports` object.

Comment: Thanks again. Isn't "I thought that I'm exporting everything inside module.exports..." exactly the same as "You have to either assign what you want to export to module.exports or attach whatever values to the default exports object."? That's why I assign module.exports to function or object-{} to grab some of it's data back. Anyway my mail is bartasb@protonmail.com I would like to ask you some few stupid questions (if it's not a problem) to not mess with this topic, to better understand what I did wrong.